# Implementing wireless sensor networks using NS2

Tags: networking, wireless, ns2

I am simulating a wireless sensor network in NS2 . I want to implement hierarchical static wireless sensor networks using clusters? How clustering be achieved in ns2. Also i wish to implement group deployment. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

For simulating WSN, you can use either nrlsensorsim patch or manasim. 
[Ns2 with manasim](http://www.nsnam.com/2013/06/mannasima-sensor-network-simulator-for.html)

For clustering, you can use LEACH protocol.
And for group deployment of nodes,you should use a famous tool [NSG-details](https://sites.google.com/site/pengjungwu/nsg)

Comment: thank you. how can we store a value(eg key) related to each node in a network using ns2